# Authorization error when using PHP mail function

Tags: server, php, email, mail, wordpress

I just noticed emails sent using a contact form in wordpress wasn't delivering and then I checked the mail log and found the following error:

```
Authorization failed (535 Authentication failed: Bad username / password)
```

This site has been in production for a few years now and this has always worked but all of a sudden I just noticed it isn't working anymore.

I tried running a script with just the mail() function to see if it was a problem with my wordpress installation or the plugin used but I got the same error.

Thanks in advance.